# Infinite looping while installing joomla 3.1.5

Tags: php, joomla, xampp

I am using Xampp v3.2.1 with Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.1 and mysql 5.6.11
When I google I have found that Joomla 3.x does not support php 5.5.1
But I dont know how to migrate php version

What I have tried is that I have tried deleteing the C:/Xamp/Php folder and want to replace it with Php 5.2 folder but then all php files are not getting deleted and apache also stop working.

Kindly suggest me the way so that I can install Joomla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the following link:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641

ou will see that Xampp 1.8.2 is the version that contains PHP 5.4 which Joomla 3.1.5 supports. Download this version and try instaling Joomla again.

If you still for some reason have problems, download an older version of Xampp such as 1.7.7 whic is the latest version that supports PHP 5.3:

http://www.oldapps.com/xampp.php?old_xampp=6586

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please suggest me any way to run Joomla 3.1.5 successfully on my current xamp version

Comment: Well I personally don't use xampp. I prefer [wampserver](http://wampserver.com/en) as I find it easier to use. For Xampp though, you can use [BitNami](http://bitnami.com/stack/xampp) which will make life easier for you :)

Answer (score 0):

joomla 3.1.5 do not work in php 5.5.x

find solution here: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=811956